# Внешняя компонента сканера отпечатков для 1С

Tags: c++

С С++ столкнулся первый раз, и навыки программирования только в 1С. На базе шаблона AddInnNative написал компоненту работы со сканером отпечатков FS-80. Компонента работает, памяти вроде не ест, но периодически сама 1С (1cv8.exe) во время сканирования выпадает с ошибкой (что-то про kernel, прошу прощения не помню, и нет возможности сейчас посмотреть, и повторяется ошибка очень редко), при этом ProcMon ничего криминального не выдает.
Может кто сможет сказать, просто глянув одним глазом на код, где допустил ошибку, так как код не большой, и написан явно криво, так как можно сказать, это франкенштейн собранный по форумам.

Лично подозреваю что ошибка в процедуре enroll, так как там не используется общий менеджер памяти 1С, в процедуре его просто не видно.

Описания переменных

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include "AddInFS80.h"
//#include "fingerprintsdk5.h"
#include <string>
//#include <iostream>
//#include <vector>

using namespace std;
//using namespace ADODB;

#import "C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll" no_namespace rename("EOF", "ADOEOF")

#pragma comment (lib, "fingerprintsdk5.lib")

#define TIME_LEN    65
#define BASE_ERRNO  7
#define TEMPLATES_SIZE  100000 //Максимальное количество шаблонов, которые можно загрузить в сканер
#define TIME_FOR_SKIP_SCAN 3 //Время в с. чтобы пропускать повторное сканирование при входе

//Строка подключения к серверу SQL
static const _bstr_t connection_string = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=usr;Password=pass;Initial Catalog=uu_ex;Data Source=server";

static const wchar_t *g_PropNames[] = { L"IsEnabled", L"Status", L"Save", L"NumFinger", L"PFR", L"Checked", L"ListPFR" };
static const wchar_t *g_MethodNames[] = { L"Enable", L"Disable", L"ShowInStatusLine",
L"StartTimer", L"StopTimer", L"LoadPicture", L"ShowMessageBox", L"Loopback", L"Enroll" };

static const wchar_t *g_PropNamesRu[] = { L"Подключен", L"СтатусСканера", L"РежимЗаписи", L"НомерПальца", L"ПФР", L"Проверен", L"СписокПФР" };
static const wchar_t *g_MethodNamesRu[] = { L"ПодключитьСканер", L"ОтключитьСканер", L"ПоказатьВСтрокеСтатуса",
L"СтартТаймер", L"СтопТаймер", L"ЗагрузитьКартинку", L"ПоказатьСообщение", L"Петля", L"НачатьСканирование" };

static const wchar_t g_kClassNames[] = L"CAddInNative"; //"|OtherClass1|OtherClass2";
static IAddInDefBase *pAsyncEvent = NULL;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------//
//Переменные для работы со сканером
//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------//

//Сканер
BSSDK_HANDLE handle;
//uint8_t templ[FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE];
int                 cnttmpls;   //Количество элементов массива шаблонов
                                //vector<BSSDK_TEMPLATE_DATA> templs;
BSSDK_TEMPLATE_DATA templs[TEMPLATES_SIZE];
_bstr_t id_pfr[TEMPLATES_SIZE];
uint8_t scan_att = 5; //Количество попыток сканирования при записи
int maxqlt = 0; //Последнее лучшее качество отпечатка
wstring last_pfr = L""; //Последний сканированный пфр
time_t last_time = 0; //Последнее время сканирования

                      //Объекты для подключения к БД
_ConnectionPtr pConn("ADODB.Connection");
_RecordsetPtr pRst;

bool                l_save;         //Записываем отпечатки в базу по переданному ПФР
wstring             l_NumFinger;    //Номер пальца 1-10
wstring             l_PFR;          //ПФР
bool                l_сhecked;      //Признак того, что палец проверен
bool                l_EnrollStarted; //Проверяет запущен ли таймер, чтобы запустить новый поток
```

Процедура работы со сканером

```
bool CAddInNative::CallAsProc(const long lMethodNum,
tVariant* paParams, const long lSizeArray)
{
switch (lMethodNum)
{

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //                          РАБОТА СО СКАНЕРОМ
    //                                FS-80
    //
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------//

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //Подключение сканера, считывание отпечатков из базы uu_ex
    //
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------//

case eMethEnable:

    int ret;

    m_boolEnabled = true;

    ret = fpsdk5_init_library(&handle);
    if (ret != BSSDK_OK)
        m_boolEnabled = false;

    ret = fpsdk5_init_scanners(handle);
    if (ret != BSSDK_OK && m_boolEnabled)
        m_boolEnabled = false;

    m_ScannerStatus = GetScannerStatus(ret);

    if (m_boolEnabled)
    {
        //Установка параметра минимального качества отпечатка, на которое реагирует сканер. Меньше этого значения считывание не происходит.
        fpsdk5_set_parameter(handle, FPSDK5_TEMPLATE_QUALITY, &min_qualityt);

        if (!m_save) //Если не режим записи, считаем все отпечатки для сравнения
        {

            //Если соединились со сканером, то создадим соединение с базой uu_ex, и заполним массив отпечатков для сравнения

            //setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
            CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
            //_ConnectionPtr pConn("ADODB.Connection");

            try
            {
                pConn.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));

                pConn->ConnectionTimeout = 100;
                pConn->CommandTimeout = 100;
                pConn->ConnectionString = connection_string;                    pConn->Open("", "", "", adConnectUnspecified);

                pRst.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset));
                pRst->CursorLocation = adUseClient;

                wstring sqlq;

                sqlq = L"SELECT * FROM FingerPrints WHERE _active = 1";

                if (!l_PFR.empty())
                {
                    sqlq += L" AND _PFR in(";

                    size_t outputSize = m_ListPFR.length() + 1;
                    char * pchtmp = new char[outputSize];
                    size_t charsConverted = 0;
                    const wchar_t * inputW = m_ListPFR.c_str();
                    wcstombs_s(&charsConverted, pchtmp, outputSize, inputW, m_ListPFR.length());

                    char * pch = strtok(pchtmp, ";");

                    while (pch != NULL)                         // пока есть лексемы
                    {
                        _bstr_t tmpbstr(pch);
                        sqlq += L"'" + tmpbstr + L"',";
                        pch = strtok(NULL, ";");
                    }

                    delete[] pchtmp;
                    inputW = nullptr;

                    sqlq += L"'')";
                }

                _bstr_t strSQL(sqlq.c_str());

                //pRst->Open(strSQL, _variant_t((IDispatch*)pConn, true), adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdUnknown);
                pRst->Open(strSQL, _variant_t((IDispatch*)pConn, true), adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdUnknown);
                int nNumFields = pRst->Fields->Count; //Полей
                int index = 0;
                cnttmpls = pRst->RecordCount; //Записей
                                              //const int ccnttmpls = cnttmpls;
                                              //BSSDK_TEMPLATE_DATA templs[cnttmpls];   //Массив шаблонов
                BSSDK_TEMPLATE_DATA tdata;

                //pRst->CacheSize = 100;
                //pRst->PageSize = 10000;

                while (!pRst->ADOEOF)
                {

                    //BSSDK_TEMPLATE_DATA tdata;
                    uint8_t tmp_templ[FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE]; //Шаблон отпечатка для записи в массив шаблонов
                    _bstr_t tmp_fld;
                    _bstr_t tmp_pfr;

                    tmp_fld = (_bstr_t)pRst->Fields->GetItem("_template")->Value; //Строка формата 0;0;0;0... для формирования массива чисел (шаблона отпечатка)
                    tmp_pfr = (_bstr_t)pRst->Fields->GetItem("_pfr")->Value;

                    id_pfr[index] = tmp_pfr; //Запомним соотвествие ПФР и номера шаблона в массиве

                                             //Разберем строку tmp_fld в массив
                    char * pch = strtok(tmp_fld, ";");
                    int index_el = 0;
                    while (pch != NULL)                         // пока есть лексемы
                    {
                        if (index_el < FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE)
                            tmp_templ[index_el] = atoi(pch);

                        index_el++;
                        pch = strtok(NULL, ";");
                    }

                    pch = nullptr;

                    //в переменную BSSDK_TEMPLATE_DATA tdata запишем информацию о шаблоне
                    tdata.id = index;
                    tdata.quality = pRst->Fields->GetItem("_quality")->Value;
                    tdata.size = FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE;
                    tdata.data = 0; //(uint8_t*)malloc(FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE);
                                    //memcpy(tdata.data, tmp_templ, FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE);
                    m_iMemory->AllocMemory((void**)&tdata.data, FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE);
                    memcpy((void*)tdata.data, (void*)&tmp_templ, FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE);

                    //templs.push_back(tdata);
                    templs[index] = tdata; //Запишем в массив шаблонов наш шаблон

                    pRst->MoveNext();
                    index++;
                }
                pRst->Close();

                m_ScannerStatus = L"Считано отпечатков " + to_wstring(cnttmpls) + L" ";
                //pConn->Close();

            }
            catch (_com_error e)
            {
                m_boolEnabled = false;
                m_ScannerStatus = L"Ошибка подключения к базе отпечатков! " + to_wstring(e.Error()) + L" ";
            }

            if (pConn != NULL)
                pConn->Close();

            CoUninitialize();
        } //if (!m_save)
        else
        {
            m_ScannerStatus = L"Режим записи ";
        } //(m_save)
    }

    break;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //Окончание подключения сканера
    //
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------//

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //Подключение асинхронного метода сканирования отпечатков
    //
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------//

case eMethEnroll:

    m_iConnect->SetEventBufferDepth(1);
    pAsyncEvent = m_iConnect;
    l_EnrollStarted = false;

    ULONG flags;
    flags = WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION; //WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT;
    WT_SET_MAX_THREADPOOL_THREADS(flags, 1);

    m_hTimerQueue = CreateTimerQueue();
    CreateTimerQueueTimer(&m_hTimer, m_hTimerQueue,
        (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)Enroll, 0, 1000, 2000, flags); // WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION);

    break;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------//
    //Отключение сканера, очистка переменных
    //
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------//

case eMethDisable:

    bool en;

    if (pAsyncEvent == NULL)
        en = false;
    else
        en = true;

    pAsyncEvent = NULL;
    l_EnrollStarted = true;

    Sleep(100);
    fpsdk5_cancel(handle);
    Sleep(100);

    //m_iConnect->CleanEventBuffer();
    if (en)
    {
        DeleteTimerQueueTimer(m_hTimerQueue, m_hTimer, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
        //DeleteTimerQueueEx(m_hTimerQueue, NULL);
        m_hTimerQueue = 0;
        m_hTimer = 0;
    }

    m_boolEnabled = false;
    fpsdk5_uninit(&handle);
    Sleep(100);
    handle = 0;

    //for (int i = 0; i < TEMPLATES_SIZE; i++)
    //  free(templs[i].data);


    break;
```

Процедура таймера

```
VOID CALLBACK Enroll(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
if (!pAsyncEvent || l_EnrollStarted)
    return;

l_EnrollStarted = true;

/*wchar_t *what = L"Тест";
wchar_t *who = L"Тест"; //= new wchar_t;
wchar_t *wqltp = L"Тест";   //= new wchar_t;

pAsyncEvent->ExternalEvent(who, what, wqltp);*/

int ret;
int qlt = 35;       //Возвращает качество отпечатка
uint8_t templ[FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE];

fpsdk5_cancel(handle);
//fpsdk5_set_state_callback(handle, NULL, &state_callback_func);

//fflush(stderr);
//fflush(stdout);

ret = fpsdk5_enroll_quality(handle, &templ, &qlt);

l_EnrollStarted = false;

if (ret != BSSDK_OK) {
    //fpsdk5_uninit(&handle);
}
else
{

    wstring whos = L"FS80_Save";
    wstring whats;
    wstring sqlq; //Строка запроса
                  //tmp = tmp + L"save " + to_wstring(l_save) + L"PFR " + l_PFR + L"NumFinger " + l_NumFinger + L"checked " + to_wstring(l_сhecked);

    if (l_save) // && qlt > maxqlt && scan_att > 0
    {

        //maxqlt = qlt;
        //scan_att--;
        whats = L"В базу записан отпечаток с качеством " + to_wstring(qlt);

        CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
        //_ConnectionPtr pConn("ADODB.Connection");

        try
        {

            //Получим текущее время для вставки в SQL
            char tbuffer[25];
            time_t tseconds = time(NULL);
            tm* timeinfo = localtime(&tseconds);
            char* tformat = "%F %H:%M:%S";
            strftime(tbuffer, 25, tformat, timeinfo);
            //std::wstring ttbuffer(25, L'#');
            //mbstowcs(&ttbuffer[0], tbuffer, 25);
            string tmp(tbuffer);
            wstring ttbuffer(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());

            //Преобразуем отпечаток в строку
            wstring stmpl;
            for (int index = 0; index < FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE; index++)
            {
                stmpl += to_wstring(templ[index]) + L";";
            }
            stmpl.pop_back();

            //Если номер пальца не установлен, то установим 1
            if (l_NumFinger == L"")
                l_NumFinger = L"1";

            //Подключимся к СКЛ, и выполним запрос
            pConn.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));

            pConn->ConnectionString = connection_string;                pConn->Open("", "", "", adConnectUnspecified);

            sqlq = L"USE uu_ex; "
                "IF (EXISTS"
                "(SELECT * FROM FingerPrints WHERE _pfr = '" + l_PFR + L"' and _number = " + l_NumFinger + L"))"
                " BEGIN "
                " UPDATE FingerPrints SET _quality = " + to_wstring(qlt) + L", _datescan = '" + ttbuffer + L"', _template = '" + stmpl + L"', _checked = " + to_wstring(l_сhecked) + L" "
                " WHERE _pfr = '" + l_PFR + L"' and _number = " + l_NumFinger + L" END"
                " ELSE BEGIN "
                " INSERT INTO FingerPrints (_pfr, _number, _checked, _quality, _datescan, _template)"
                " VALUES"
                " ('" + l_PFR.c_str() + L"','" + l_NumFinger.c_str() + L"'," + to_wstring(l_сhecked) + L"," + to_wstring(qlt) + L",'" + ttbuffer + L"','" + stmpl + L"')"
                " END;";

            _bstr_t strSQL(sqlq.c_str());
            //variant_t *recaff = 0;

            pConn->Execute(strSQL, 0, adExecuteNoRecords);

        }
        catch (_com_error e)
        {
            whos = L"FS80_Error";
            whats = L"Ошибка записи в базу отпечатка " + to_wstring(e.Error()) + L" " + sqlq;
        }

        if (pConn != NULL)
            pConn->Close();

        CoUninitialize();

    }
    /*else
    {
    whats = L"Качество отпечатка " + to_wstring(qlt) + L" не больше записанного ранее " + to_wstring(maxqlt) + L". Не записан.";
    }

    if (scan_att == 0)
    {
    whats = L"Исчерпано количество попыток сканирования, в базу записан отпечаток с качеством " + to_wstring(maxqlt);
    }*/

    if (!l_save)
    {

        whos = L"FS80_Scan";

        int fndindex;
        //IMemoryManager     *l_iMemory;
        //l_iMemory = 0;

        BSSDK_TEMPLATE_DATA tdata;
        tdata.id = 0;
        tdata.quality = 0;
        tdata.size = FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE;
        tdata.data = (uint8_t*)malloc(FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE);
        //memcpy(tdata.data, &templ, FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE);
        //l_iMemory->AllocMemory((void**)tdata.data, FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE);
        memcpy((void*)tdata.data, (void*)&templ, FINGERPRINT_TEMPLATE_SIZE);

        BSSDK_TEMPLATE_DATA * ttdata = new BSSDK_TEMPLATE_DATA(tdata);

        //Найдем отпечаток в массиве отпечатков
        fpsdk5_identify(handle, ttdata
            , templs,
            cnttmpls, &fndindex);

        delete ttdata;
        free(tdata.data);

        if (fndindex == -1)
        {
            whos = L"FS80_Error";
            whats = L"Отпечаток не найден в базе!";
        }
        else
        {
            wstring tmp_pfr(id_pfr[fndindex], SysStringLen(id_pfr[fndindex]));
            whats = L"" + tmp_pfr;
            time_t tseconds = time(NULL);
            //Если сканирование ранее чем через TIME_FOR_SKIP_SCAN секунд, пропустим событие.
            if (tseconds - last_time < TIME_FOR_SKIP_SCAN) //last_pfr == tmp_pfr && 
            {
                whos = L"FS80_Error";
                whats = L"Попытка отсканироваться повторно ранее чем через " + to_wstring(TIME_FOR_SKIP_SCAN) + L" сек.";
            }
            else
            {
                last_time = tseconds;
            }

            last_pfr = tmp_pfr;
        }

    }

    wchar_t *what; //= new wchar_t;
    wchar_t *who;   //= new wchar_t;
    wchar_t *wqltp; //= new wchar_t;
    wstring sqlt;
    sqlt = to_wstring(qlt);
    what = const_cast<wchar_t *>(whats.c_str());
    who = const_cast<wchar_t *>(whos.c_str());
    wqltp = const_cast<wchar_t *>(sqlt.c_str());

    pAsyncEvent->ExternalEvent(who, what, wqltp);

    //Очищаем переменные

}

//free(templ);

}
```

Comment: Словите ошибку. Опубликуйте. Получите стак-трейс, вычислите в какой процедуре, а лучше в какой строке ошибка. Если вы догадываетесь о проблемном месте - обверните это место в `try`-`catch`. Гадать по коду мы не умеем.

Comment: Из мелочи... CoInitializeEx - нужно делать один раз, при старте программы. CoUninitialize можно тогда не делать.

Comment: Спасибо, за подсказки. Посмотрю что такое стак-трейс :) и попробую его сделать.

Comment: Попробуйте все выкинуть из кода и оставить только заглушку, которая всегда выдает константу. Если падения прекратятся, то постепенно добавляйте участки кода. Когда падения возобновятся, значит тут и была ошибка.